# Application Error deploying on Heroku

Tags: logging, heroku

I deployed a basic app shell on Heroku, but it is giving me this error.

Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

I ran 'heroku logs' and it gave me this:

```
2013-06-13T21:02:08.867684+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/ host=stark-earth-3664.herokuapp.com fwd="76.222.223.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-06-13T21:02:08.961289+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=stark-earth-3664.herokuapp.com fwd="76.222.223.146" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

The only change I made to the basic RoR app was change the SQLite gem files and add the DB gemfile.

Thanks in advance for your help. I cannot decipher the Heroku logs ...

J. Olivero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Your app has stopped* indicates that your app might need to be restarted. Try running `heroku restart`.

Comment: restart didn't work for me.  I had to scale web dyno to 1:  `heroku ps:scale web=1`

Comment: Interesting. Had you scaled your dynos to zero? Because Heroku enables one web dyno on your app by default at the time of installation.

Answer (score -1):

check scaling of your app , maybe you got web dynos to 0
try : $ heroku ps:scale web=1 
 then $ heroku open

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25935225)

Comment: the above error renders when your dynos is 0 , it worked in my case